# Issue parsing data using fgetcsv() - expects parameter to be resource

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm getting this error when parsing data from a URL using fgetcsv() in php.

**Here's my Error:**
PHP Warning:  fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /testing.php on line 20

**Note**: I have tired a possible solution with no luck [PHP return error when using fgetcsv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327833/php-return-error-when-using-fgetcsv)

**Dataset: What I'm trying to parse with fgetcsv()**

```
{"pos":[{"pos":"1","person":"John","place":"8","score":"109","round":"1"}, {"pos":"2","person":"Mary","score":"80"},{"pos":"3","person":"Luke Guthrie","place":"7*","score":"7","round":"1"}, {"pos":"4","person":"Charles","score":"3"},{"pos":"5","person":"Sean","place":"8","score":"4","round":"1"}, {"pos":"6","person":"Rob","score":"60"},   {"pos":"7","person":"Dan","score":"76"},{…
```

**Here's my php file:**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "player";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  $f_pointer=fopen("URL/api/v2/projects/xxx/last_ready_run/data","r"); 



  while(! feof($f_pointer))

  {
      $ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);


 $sql="INSERT INTO scores(pos,person,score,place,score,round)values('$ar[0]','$ar[1]','$ar[2]','$ar[3]','$ar[4]','$ar[5]')";
 $conn->query($sql); 
 echo $sql;
 echo "<br>";


  }
 ?>
```

Comment: You're trying to parse json data with fgetcsv()?!? Good luck!

Comment: Sorry my bad, I used the wrong error code - i'll edit the question now thanks

Comment: And a Boolean value in $f_pointer instead of a resource probably means that the fopen() failed

Comment: Sorry but would this work with a  URL ending in format=csv? The URL im using downloads a CSV and doesnt show it on the browser

Answer (score 0):

Try again with some error handling.

```
$f_pointer=fopen("URL/api/v2/projects/xxx/last_ready_run/data","r"); 
if ( !$f_pointer ) {
  trigger_error('fopen failed', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Anyway fgetcsv() is not the right function to parse json. [json_decode()](http://docs.php.net/json_decode) is.